# Create collaborative feedback

Tags: collaboration, comment-system

Do you know if there's a website that allows us to create a collaborative form with a commenting and vote/like system (just as you can see here, on facebook or reddit) ?

I end up here after searching a long time on the internet and I didn't find what I was looking for.

I need to collect the reaction of 40 people on 70 propositions. The idea is to allow a person to like or not a proposition (a ranking system would be great !), comment a proposition and like/dislike each other comments.

I hope I've been clear enough, let me know otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while but maybe it helps anyway. I am one of the developers of PollUnit. A few months ago we launched a new feature "collect ideas". I think this is exactly what you are looking for.

The only feature you mentioned we do not offer is rating comments. If it is still important for you, we could add this feature (let me know).

More information: https://pollunit.com/en/collect-ideas-and-feedback